# Getting desktop version in Cordova WebView/InAppBrowser using User Agent

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, user-agent

I am trying to gain access to a desktop view of a website that I am loading into the InAppBrowser plugin for my Cordova 5.0 application.

I have tried a few things:

1) setting user agent preference in config.xml

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.45 Safari/535.19" />
```

2) setting the useragent by modifying the navigator getter

```
window.navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
                                              return 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.45 Safari/535.19';
                                              });
```

Both without any luck...

Has anyone else here had much luck with other methods?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which page are you trying to load? maybe they don't use the user agent to load the mobile version

Comment: Thanks for the response back @jcesarmobile but unfortunately it does use agent sniffing. I just tried loading the website up in chromes mobile device emulator, got the error message, then spoofed the UA string then it let me through :(

I know there is a plugin for android to change the UA but I am building for iOS

Comment: there is a pull request on the inAppBrowser plugin to add the user agent change https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/94